# Operator || cannot be applied to operands of type "bool" and "bool?"

Tags: c#, null, nullable, c#-9.0, .net-6.0

Try to compare the bools isMetaField, isIntrospectionSchema, isWithinGraphQlType and fieldDefinition.

`isMetaField` = `bool`
`introspectionSchema` = `bool`
`isWithinGraphQlType` = `bool?`
`fieldDefinition`  = `bool`

```
var fieldDefinition = context.TypeInfo.GetFieldDef();
if (fieldDefinition == null) // it's a field that doesn't exist
    return;
var isMetaField = fieldAst.Name.StartsWith("__");
var parentType = context.TypeInfo.GetParentType().GetType();
var isIntrospectionSchema = fieldDefinition is SchemaMetaFieldType;
var isWithinGraphQlType = (parentType.IsGenericType ? parentType.GenericTypeArguments[0] : parentType).FullName?.StartsWith("GraphQL.");

if (isMetaField || isIntrospectionSchema || isWithinGraphQlType || fieldDefinition.HasMetadata("AllowUnauthenticatedAccess"))
    return;
```

The variable `isWithinGraphQlType` has the possibility to be null so I can't compare it with the other bools but need too. How can I do this?

Comment: That depends. Does `null` represent `true` or `false` in your case? If `false`, use `.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: `a_bool || (nullable_bool ?? true_or_false)` — the value has be resolved to a non-nullable value first (pick the appropriate one); unlike SQL, no tri-logic logical operators in C#!

Comment: If it's true then I want to run the if statement/return;

Comment: Don't think `nullablebool ?? true` would work because wouldn't it just always return true?

Comment: @John_Mason27 That would be true if `nullablebool` is true or null and false if it is false.  The value after the `??` is only used if it's `null`

Comment: You could do it like:
`if (isMetaField || isIntrospectionSchema || (isWithinGraphQlType ?? false) || fieldDefinition.HasMetadata("AllowUnauthenticatedAccess"))`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the comments`.GetValueOrDefault();` was the nicest solution.